# How to compare int with string in linq where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a `string` parameter which that i want to compare with `int` and `string` in `Linq query`.

```
var query=(from GRD in _tblMembers.GetQueryable()
           select new MembersModel
           {
               SchoolID = GRD.SchoolID,
               MemberID = GRD.MemberID,
               MemberReferenceID = GRD.MemberReferenceID,
               MemberTypeID = GRD.MemberTypeID,
               MemberNo = GRD.MemberNo,
               MemberName = GRD.MemberName,
               CellNo = GRD.CellNo,                                         
            }).Where(z => z.MemberName.Contains(param.sSearch) || z.MemberTypeID.Contains(param.sSearch)).ToString();
```

when i tried to convert database parameter to to string type using `ToString()` method as follows.

```
.Where(z => z.MemberName.Contains(param.sSearch) || z.MemberTypeID.ToString().Contains(param.sSearch)).ToString();
```

linq throw run time exception.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression.

How can i do coversion in linq query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx)

```
.Where(z => z.MemberName.Contains(param.sSearch) 
            || SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)z.MemberTypeID).Contains(param.sSearch))
.ToString();
```

Comment: `var query =
                    (from c in ctx.A
                     where c.ID==cl
                     select new Accoun
                     {
                         ex = c.Type
                     }).Distinct();`
Here `cl` is `int` and c.ID is `string` but I want to compare them in `int` format. I have tried with `where Convert.ToInt32(c.ID)==cl` but getting `invalid where condition` error